# Drop Down Menu hidden behind the slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html5-canvas

The drop down menu is hidden behind the slider on chrome. I haven't checked internet explorer yet. I've tried setting the main menu and submenu with position:relative and high z-index, and the slider wrapper as position: relative and low z-index. However, it's still not working.

The website I'm working on is: http://www.scraptsy.com

Slider_wrapper

```
.rev_slider_wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
}
.tp-bannertimer {
    z-index: 20!important;
}
.rev_slider iframe {
    z-index: 100;

}
```

Main Menu

```
#header-section > #main-nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    /*background: url('images/triangular.png');*/
    background-color: #C17B48;
    border-top: 1px solid #E25879 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E25879 !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#header-section #main-nav, #header-section #main-nav .sub-menu, #header-section #main-nav .sub-menu ul, #header-section #main-nav .sub-menu li,  #header-section #main-nav .sub-menu li a{
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Not seeing what you're saying.

Comment: It only appears on the chrome browser. When the slider changes its slide, the slide moves forward and hides the sub menu. Not sure why though...

Comment: @wag0325 : Try this in your css `#menu * {z-index: 999;}`. Instead of **#menu** put your **nav bar id**...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your slider or image div
"style="position: absolute; z-ndex:-1000;"

It worked for me.